# View from inside clashing galaxies

Tags: galaxies

[The below image from Hubble](https://spacetelescope.org/images/heic1919a/) show two clashing galaxies. Is there a simulation (or whatever) as how the sky would look withing those galaxies? For example, would the night sky be noticeably brighter than ours?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[NASA's Hubble Shows Milky Way is Destined for Head-On Collision](https://www.nasa.gov/mission_pages/hubble/science/milky-way-collide.html).

[image]

The brightness is exaggerated.